# feature label is not showing ArcGis 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis-runtime

I have my app configured with arcgis version 10.2 and 100.2.
I have a feature layer in that every feature has a label for its code to display.

What happening hear is in arcgis 10.2 only the feature is displaying but the label doesnot display

and on arcgis 100.2 previously neither the feature nor its label displays.
but in this we have a query function with .LoadAll parameter. By implementing this method both the label and feature is getting saved in feature table.

But in 10.2 I was not able to display its label

[image: without label] -----  [image: With Label]

How should I show the label ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **[outFields](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/10-2/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_feature_layer.html#aa25e75eca137659051ff47b3d223542b)** property on the 10.2.x AGSFeatureLayer. To replicate 100.x's **loadAll** behavior, set this to **["*"]** (as described in the documentation).